# Executing script in vim creates unwanted whitespace in terminal

Tags: python, vim, plugins, whitespace

I'm writing a vim plugin and at one point in my code I used silent bang (!) to execute a python script. This is executed when the plugin is loaded, in other words, whenever vim starts up. Let's say that when I start vim I am currently on the top line of my terminal window. When I then exit vim, I am suddenly on the bottom line of my terminal window with the whitespace in between the command I just typed and my current position. This is really annoying and if anyone has any insight, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Here is an example:

In sample_plugin.vim:

`silent !path/to/script.py`

I start vim; I am positioned at the top of the terminal.
I quit vim; I am now positioned at the bottom of the terminal.

Unfortunately, I can't post images because I'm new.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Post links to the images (in the question) Someone will format them for you